# How can I change the position of the mouse cursor in OpenGL/Glut?

Tags: opengl, mouse, glut

I'm writing a simple game and I'm going to have the mouse control the camera (using GlutPassiveMotionFunc).

I'm going to pitch and yaw based off the mouse difference between callbacks, however I think it would be a good idea to "force" the mouse back to the center of the screen every time they tried to move it.  This way their cursor won't be at the edge of the screen and they can't move any further in that direction.

What Glut / OpenGL command can I use to force the position of the mouse to change?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `glutWarpPointer(x, y)`, where `x` and `y` (both `int`s) are in pixels (relative to the window's origin). For example:

```
glutWarpPointer(windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2);
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me, since the glutWarpPointer(x,y) also resets the mouse positions.

Comment: What do you mean by "resets the mouse position"? That's what it is supposed to do (in this case, you read the mouse position before calling glutWarpPointer to re-center the mouse). Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer. What i meant was that after i use glutWrapPointer function, if i print out the x and y values, i could not catch the change on the cursor and it always prints out the values inside the glutWrapPointer function that i provided. What i did to fix it was to move this function inside the Animate function of openGl and it worked fine.