# Move mouse without glutWarpPointer

Tags: c++, winapi, glut

I'm attempting to move the camera via gluLookAt in my OpenGL app similar to how the camera moves in a FPS game. It works, however, I would like to center the mouse after moving it, to disallow the mouse from ever reaching the edge of the screen. After doing some research, I found glutWarpPointer is a viable option, however, I get the sense that professional game developers only utilize the basic OpenGL commands, instead of something like glutWarpPointer, or glutSolidCube, or glutSolidSphere. Am I correct in assuming this?

In my WndProc function, I set the look for my gluLookAt under the WM_MOUSEMOVE message in my switch block. I also realize that SendInput would achieve what I want, but from my understanding SendInput would trigger another WM_MOUSEMOVE when the cursor goes to the middle of the screen, essentially reversing my original movement of the mouse, and not moving the camera's look at all.

Any ideas?

Edit: I don't think there exists a function that does not call a WM_MOUSEMOVE message. I think the proper route is to create a flag that determines whether the WM_MOUSEMOVE was invoked by a SetCursorPos, and if it was, do not change the camera's look.

Comment: Wait, why do you have a WndProc if you're thinking of using GLUT?

Comment: I don't want to use GLUT, just simple OpenGL.

Comment: Here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784322/how-can-i-change-the-position-of-the-mouse-cursor-in-opengl-glut

Comment: Did you even read my post? I don't want to use glutWarpPointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`SetCursorPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to relocate the mouse cursor if you're on Windows.

Comment: This actually calls a WM_MOUSEMOVE message. Although this is a good suggestion, I'll mark it as accepted because it does help.